# Shouldn't context be more clear?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23550/why-were-we-taught-virtually-nothing-about-the-holocaust-during-the-fifties-and), [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/what-factors-prevented-the-legality-of-secession-being-pursued-via-the-courts-pr) and in a few other questions, I get the feeling the author assumes all readers to somehow understand these questions are asked from a US point of view and title leaves out context completely. 
This has bothered me a bit when passively browsing thru history-se. Is the site US centric intentionally, or is this something that could be improved?

Comment: Maybe it isn't as bad as I thought,  looking through old questions, they usually have proper tags or titles. I've would prefer both tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good question yes. Those are good US-centric examples, but I know I've come across some that assumed knowledge from other cultures too. For instance, using only last names that I had never heard of before and had to Google. Ick.

I'd say its perfectly reasonable to edit such questions to add some missing context (eg: **President** Lincoln, together with a [usa](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) tag would probably be sufficient). Sadly, the OP's who do this are often unaware that other people don't share all their context, and thus can't really be relied on to do it themselves every time.

Comment: okay great, i added some tags to one of the questions :)